# Can't make date picker full screen in activity

Tags: android, layout, datepicker

I want to add date picker in full screen. I used match_marent but it can't work. There has a margin at the right of the screen. Can't removed it.
This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/dp_starting_date"
tools:context=".StartingDateFragment">

<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

It's look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dp_starting_date"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartingDateFragment" >

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleX="1.1"
        android:scaleY="1.1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```